# Lapply vs apply

Tags: r

```
X=c(1,2,3,4)
```

I want to apply a function on this vector; suppose I want to have the square of its elements. I'm getting it by applying `lapply`; but with `apply` I'm getting an error.

```
apply(X,function(x){x^2}) 
lapply(X,function(x){x^2})
```

Can we use it with `lapply` only?

Answer (score 5):

We don't need `lapply`.  It can be directly applied on the `vector`

```
X^2
#[1]  1  4  9 16
```

---

Regarding the `apply` syntax, it needs a `MARGIN`.  For `data.frame/matrix/data.table/tbl_df` etc. have dimensions, but `vector` doesn't have.  So, it is not usable here.

The `lapply` syntax is correct, but it returns a `list` of elements.  Instead `sapply` can be used.  However, all of these are not needed for this task